# When is an updated app downloadable from the App Store on the iPhone and iPad?

Tags: ios-appstore

Example: Pokemon Go 0.83 was available yesterday around noon (Nov 27, 2017), and one of the person in our group downloaded it around noon.

But I checked and checked, even restarted the App Store app, rebooted the iPhone, and could not see the Update button. Not until about 10 or 11pm.

And today I wanted to see how the app looks like on the iPhone X, and again, I restarted the App Store app, and rebooted the iPhone X, and there is still no Update button, when it is 5pm and 28 hours after somebody was able to update it.

When is it supposed to be available and is there a way to force the update to show up?

Comment: Apple staggers release because of bandwidth, they can't deliver some apps to every customer at once.

Comment: but any customer who keeps on waiting and waiting, and even if they want to force update it, cannot, and just have to wait helplessly. Is that good? What about letting me update at 1am or 3am or 6am? There won't be tons of people updating in my area, and actually at 1am, there is hardly any soul updating it in the whole Pacific Coast all the way to the East Coast which is 4am, or does it just need to keep me wait for 5 hours, 8 hours, 16 hours? How long?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way you can try, not guaranteed to work but it might:

> Delete your app, and then just install it again

the App Store app / server might decide it would waste too much bandwidth to let you download the old version and then update you within a day or two, so it will just give you the latest version.